# SAS find date of birth from age

Tags: date, sas

I have a dataset that has VisitDate and AgeAtVisit. I need DateOfBirth.

I know that if I went from VisitDate and DateOfBirth I can calculate AgeAtVisit from 
      AgeAtVisit = intck('year',DateOfBirth,VisitDate);

However I am not sure how to go backwards.

My data is as so:

```
   ID       VisitDate        AgeAtVisit
    1         01/01/2000        73.25
    2         03//03/2000       74.22
    3         06/06/2006       65.30
```

How can I go from this to date of birth?

I thought about trying to manually do an equation like

```
  age = (Date of visit -date of birth)/365.25
```

but I can't just rearrange because I can't subtract age from date of visit. I can't use YearDiff because I only have one date. I don't think I can use intck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do what you were suggesting.  Dates are numbers of days since 1/1/1960, so you can add/subtract days with impunity.  You might be off by a day or so across a lifetime, though, given the imperfection of leap years (2000 was a leap year fortunately so unless you have > 116 yo people, you're probably okay).

```
data have;
input ID       VisitDate  :mmddyy10. AgeAtVisit;
format visitDate date9.;
datalines;
    1         01/01/2000        73.25
    2         03/03/2000       74.22
    3         06/06/2006       65.30
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  dateOfBirth = visitDate - 365.25*ageAtVisit;
  format dateOfBirth date9.;
run;
```

If you actually need perfect accuracy, you'd need something better than what you have for `AgeAtVisit`.

Comment: Thanks. I would have preferred perfect accuracy but seeing as this is the data I was given this will have to do.  So because dates are numbers I can basically use them as a number in all similar equations. That makes sense. I thought I couldn't because we have intx and yeardiff. but I guess that just corrects for the leap year.

Comment: `intnx` and `yeardiff` are just convenience functions - neither does anything you couldn't fundamentally do yourself, just in more complexity.  I thought maybe `intnx` would accept a noninteger number of years, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.